# How to check if youtube authentication has worked using OAUTH

Tags: asp.net, .net, youtube, youtube-api

Here is some code that uses authentication using YouTube API.

```
Public Function GetService(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As YouTubeService

        Dim service As YouTubeService = New YouTubeService("test", "xxxxxxxx")
        service.setUserCredentials(username, password)

        Return service

    End Function
```

Now if i type in some wrong credentials YouTube doesn't specificity if the user is authenticate successfully. Is there another method to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `QueryClientLoginToken()` method on service object.

read here for more details  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/youmanager.aspx